# Meaning of "sex will melt your face."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I heard on a TV show that sex with some particular woman is so good, it will **melt your face**. I could find the explanation for this expression.

Comment: I've heard this expression a number of times in non-sexual contexts (often in the context of music).  Unfortunately, I only know what the expression means, I can't explain how it came about.

Comment: @snailboat: So it just means 'it gives you immense pleasure'?

Comment: Not "the sex with", but "sex with" or "having sex with".

Comment: It is possible for *sex* to be determined by *the*.

Comment: I've always taken it to mean (and it's not uncommon) that something is so hot and mind blowing it'll 'melt your face'. It's so good you won't be able to handle it.

Comment: Probably related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark. Some characters got their faces melted off, literally!, when they opened the ark in the movie. (Search for *"As Belloq, Toht and Dietrich all scream in terror, the Ark turns its fury on them: Dietrich's head shrivels up, Toht's face is melted off his skull and Belloq's head explodes"* in the mentioned Wikipedia page.)

Comment: I have always assumed that since something awe-inspiring can be described as '*jaw-dropping*' that if you want to take it further your whole face must drop and the only way to have that happen is to have it melt. But that's just how I reconcile it to myself, I have no idea how it really evolved.

Answer (score 1):

It [means](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=melt%20faces) something that is **extremely intense** and **in your face**. For example,

> That band plays some serious meltface.